# Forcing base class functions to be used from the base class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, super

The answer to this question is probably **"W-what!? What the !@#$-- Stop!! That's a terrible idea!"**, but I would like to hear your thoughts...

I have two classes and one inherits from the other.

```
class A(object):
    def t1(self):
        self.t2()
    def t2(self):
        print "A"

class B(A):
    def t1(self):
        super(B, self).t1()
    def t2(self):
        print "B"

>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a.tl()
A
>>> b.t1()
B
```

In this example `B.t1` calls the `super` function, to call `A.t1`, but when it hits `self.t2()`, in the `A.t1` function it returns to the `B` class to perform `B.t2()`

How would I be able to force calls from the base class to stay in the base class? This is all I could come up with, and it works, but I'm thinking there's a better solution.

```
class A(object):
    def t1(self):
        if type(self) == A:
            self.t2()
        else:
            super(type(self), self).t2()
    def t2(self):
        print "A"

class B(A):
    def t1(self):
        super(B, self).t1()
    def t2(self):
        print "B"

>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a.tl()
A
>>> b.t1()
A
```

Answer (score 1):

In `A`'s `t1` you can do `A.t2(self)`.  However, this kind of setup is probably an indicator of a fragile design.

Answer (score 1):

You use double underscore aka [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

```
class A(object):
    def t1(self):
        self.__t2()  # <---- changed the call
    def t2(self):
        print "A"

    __t2 = t2  # private copy of original t2() method

>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a.tl()
A
>>> b.t1()
A
```

But name mangling has a huge default : it make unittesting more difficult and ugly if the function has only the double underscore as name.

But I'm with @BrenBarn, it feel like a fragile design.